# How to export WordPress posts?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, export

How to export WordPress posts to XML or CSV? I am looking for a neat way to do it with the help of `PHP`.

**Note:** I don't want to do it via the admin panel because I want to automate it.

Answer (score 3):

To do it from PHP, do it like this:

1. Get all posts marked `publish` from the database.
2. Export them to an array by using following array2xml function:

.

```
<?php
function array2xml($array, $name='array', $standalone=TRUE, $beginning=TRUE)
{
    global $nested;

    if ($beginning)
    {
        if ($standalone) header("content-type:text/xml;charset=utf-8");
        $output .= '<'.'?'.'xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"'.'?'.'>' . PHP_EOL;
        $output .= '<' . $name . '>' . PHP_EOL;
        $nested = 0;
    }

    // This is required because XML standards do not allow a tag to start with a number or symbol, you can change this value to whatever you like:
    $ArrayNumberPrefix = 'ARRAY_NUMBER_';

    foreach ($array as $root=>$child)
    {
        if (is_array($child))
        {
            $output .= str_repeat(" ", (2 * $nested)) . '  <' . (is_string($root) ? $root : $ArrayNumberPrefix . $root) . '>' . PHP_EOL;
            $nested++;
            $output .= array2xml($child,NULL,NULL,FALSE);
            $nested--;
            $output .= str_repeat(" ", (2 * $nested)) . '  </' . (is_string($root) ? $root : $ArrayNumberPrefix . $root) . '>' . PHP_EOL;
        }
        else
        {
            $output .= str_repeat(" ", (2 * $nested)) . '  <' . (is_string($root) ? $root : $ArrayNumberPrefix . $root) . '><![CDATA[' . $child . ']]></' . (is_string($root) ? $root : $ArrayNumberPrefix . $root) . '>' . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    if ($beginning)
        $output .= '</' . $name . '>';

    return $output;
}

//connect to database and select database (edit yourself)
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("databasename");

//Get all posts whose status us published.
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $posts[] = $row;

//convert to array and print it on screen:
echo "<pre>";
echo htmlentities(array2xml($posts, 'posts', false));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your Wordpress setup, take a look at `wp-admin/export.php` lines 28-48 (on a 3.0 setup).
This is the code that generates the XML file downloadable in the admin. You could maybe use that in your own code (unfortunately, it's not organized into a function, so you'll have to do some copy-paste-ing).

Also, you could automate the downloading of http://yourblog/wp-admin/export.php?download, as this URI would always redirect to a fresh XML export. You'll have to deal with inputting your credentials for that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the [Wordpress blog...](http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2006/06/12/xml-import-export/)

> You’ll find the export and import
>   options now under “Manage” in your
>   blog admin area. The XML format is an
>   extended version of RSS 2.0, and it
>   will be built into the next
>   downloadable release of WordPress
>   (2.1).